# Spring mongoDB aggregation group on date minute subset

Tags: spring, mongodb, datetime, group-by, aggregation

I'm running Spring 2.2.7 with spring-data-mongodb.

I've an entity called **BaseSample** stored in a **samples** MongoDb collection and I want to group records by minute from the created date and getting the average value collected. I don't know how to use the DateOperators.Minute in the group aggregation operation.

**detailed explanation**

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "samples")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BaseSample extends Message {

    private float value;
    private UdcUnitEnum unit;
    private float accuracy;
    public LocalDateTime recorded;

}
```

that extends a **Message** class

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Message {

    @Indexed
    private String sensorUuId;
    @Indexed
    private String fieldUuId;
    @Indexed
    private String baseStationUuId;
    @Indexed
    private Date created;

}
```

on which I want to apply this query

```
db.samples.aggregate ([
    {
        $match: {
            $and : [ {fieldUuId:"BS1F1"}, {unit: "DGC"}, {created : {$gte : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:00:00.0Z")}}, {created : {$lt : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:15:00.0Z")}}]
            }
    },
    {
        $group: {
        _id : { $minute : "$created"},
        date : {$first : {$dateToString:{date: "$created", format:"%Y-%m-%d"}}},        
        time : {$first : {$dateToString:{date: "$created", format:"%H:%M"}}},
        unit : {$first : "$unit"},
        data : { $avg : "$value"}
        }

    },
    {
    $sort: {date:1, time:1}
    }
])
```

on the **samples** collection (exerpt)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed296150af58a1c60c4f154"),
    "value" : 90.85242462158203,
    "unit" : "HPA",
    "accuracy" : 0.6498473286628723,
    "recorded" : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:21:25.850Z"),
    "sensorUuId" : "458f0ffd-13f9-466d-81a1-8d2e1c808da9",
    "fieldUuId" : "BS1F2",
    "baseStationUuId" : "BS1",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:21:25.777Z"),
    "_class" : "org.open_si.udc_common.models.BaseSample"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed296150af58a1c60c4f155"),
    "value" : 40.84038162231445,
    "unit" : "HPA",
    "accuracy" : 0.030185099691152573,
    "recorded" : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:21:25.950Z"),
    "sensorUuId" : "b396264f-fcd5-4653-8ac8-358ca3a4cb87",
    "fieldUuId" : "BS2F3",
    "baseStationUuId" : "BS2",
    "created" : ISODate("2020-05-30T17:21:25.868Z"),
    "_class" : "org.open_si.udc_common.models.BaseSample"
}
```

I coded the following method to get the average value of samples grouped per minute for a selected unit type (degree, ...) in a selected field (sensors logical group)

public List aggregateFromField(String fieldUuId, UdcUnitEnum unit, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to, Optional pageNumber, Optional pageSize){

```
Pageable paging = new PagingHelper(pageNumber, pageSize).getPaging();

MatchOperation fieldMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("fieldUuId").is(fieldUuId));
MatchOperation unitMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("unit").is(unit.name()));
MatchOperation fromDateMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("created").gte(from));
MatchOperation toDateMatch = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("created").lt(to));

DateOperators.Minute minute = DateOperators.Minute.minuteOf("created");

GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("created")
        .first("created").as("date")
        .first("created").as("time")
        .first("unit").as("unit")
        .avg("value").as("avg")
        ;

SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "$date")).and(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "$time"));
SkipOperation skip = Aggregation.skip(paging.getOffset());
LimitOperation limit = Aggregation.limit(paging.getPageSize());

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        fieldMatch,
        unitMatch,
        fromDateMatch,
        toDateMatch,
        group,
        sort,
        skip,
        limit
);


AggregationResults<SampleAggregationResult> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(BaseSample.class), SampleAggregationResult.class);

return results.getMappedResults();
```

}

this result class is :

```
@Data
public class SampleAggregationResult {

    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String unit;
    private float data;

}
```

Any idea on using the DateOperators.Minute type in the agrregation group operation ?

thnaks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting the modern `LocalDateTime`. You need to use `DateTimeFormatter`. No matter if using one or the other, beware of the case of format pattern letters, `YYYY` and `yyyy` don’t mean the same thing and won’t always produce the same result.

Comment: you're right, actualy I changed my code yesterday. now the aggregateFromField method use LocalDateTime objects in the from/to DateMatch operations and it works fine without parsing to string (checked in testing). The controller in the gateway project call the service use private final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m"); to provide the input LocalDateTime objects. Thanks for your remark @Ole